# Is it possible to start an Express.js server in the browser through Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Is it possible to start an Express.js server in the browser through Angular?

I would like to run some Node scripts in the Express server called by an Angular component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo mean you want to instantiate an Express server within the browser? I don't think this is possible, as browsers are meant to connect to web servers, not be web servers themselves. Browsers' security restrictions will probably not allow a TCP port to be opened. You can, however, run the express server as a separate process and use AJAX to communicate with it and run your scripts. This can be done through various of front end libraries. Some examples are Axios and RequestJS (I have used both succesfully to communicate a browser with an express server). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have some server listening. If you send a request from the browser to start the server, who is going to be listening for that "start server" request?

A better idea might be to have the server running, and listening for requests for the different types of scripts you might run. You could have routes registered in express like '/do-thing-1' and '/do-thing2'. Then, when you're ready to run one of those scripts, it would be invoked by sending a request to the appropriate route.