# Getting error on my express project: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

For some reason I'm getting the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')` on my javascript file. From what I see online, people seem to find that importing {response} from express was the culprit, but I'm not doing any of that.

```
import { Button } from '../Button';
import "./index.css";
import {clientId,clientSecret} from "./config.json"
import passport from "passport";
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var DiscordStrategy = require('passport-discord').Strategy;

export const OAuth = (): JSX.Element => {
    var scopes = ['identify', 'guilds', 'guilds.members.read'];

    passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
        clientID: clientId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
        scope: scopes
    }))

    app.get('/auth/discord', passport.authenticate('discord'));
    app.get('/auth/discord/callback', passport.authenticate('discord', {
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }), function(req:any, res:any) {
        console.log(res)
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000') // Successful auth
    });

    
    async function openLink(url:any) {
        window.open(url)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={async() => await openLink("link goes here")} className="discordconnect">
                Connect Discord
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default OAuth;
```

Comment: This is a really weird mix of frontend (clientside) React.js code with backend (serverside) Express.js code. Those are two independent applications. This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: What line makes reports that error? What is the stack trace?

Comment: When I checked, the line ```const app = express();``` seems to be the cause. When I removed it, the error went away

Comment: Follow up question: Why are you creating an express app in a React component? And how are you running this code? If you are trying to run express from the browser, that's not going to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542358/is-it-possible-to-start-an-express-js-server-in-the-browser-through-angular

Comment: Would the express app have to be run separately from the react component? I don't have much experience with web dev

Comment: You might want to start with [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/1048572) then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

This error seems to happen when you are trying to run express in a browser environment.

(See [code sandbox with the same error](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-golick-5w9p6h?file=/src/index.tsx))

***Express*** is a web server. It runs on node.js and is typically started from your terminal prompt on your computer. It provides responses to http requests sent from a browser.

***React*** is a front end UI framework that run inside your browser. It manipulates the HTML content displayed on the page according to loaded data and user interaction with that page.

It looks like you are trying to start an express app from a React component running in your browser. This is not supported by Express. Express cannot be run in the browser. In fact, no server can be hosted from a web browser due to browser security policies.

---

I don't know what it is you are trying to do, but you need to fundamentally rethink your approach here.

Typically when you begin developing this, you would create a server with express that *serves* a react application. You start the server from your computer's command line terminal, and then navigate to a URL served by that server which loads your react app in your browser.

You never create a server from a React component because that just isn't possible, nor does it make very much sense.

Comment: "your computer", "your browser" - the *typical* place to run a web server is a computer in a data center. And react runs in the browser of whoever visits the website.

Comment: You’re right, of course, but I’m talking about step 1 for someone who tried to run a web server from React here.